# Simple database table comparison using DataTable.Merge and DataTable.GetChanges

Tags: c#, datatable, database-comparison

We are converting our application from using Sql Server Express (let's call this version 3) to Sql Server Compact Edition (let's call this version 4). I am trying to make sure that upgrades from previous versions (versions 1 and 2) are the same in the new product (version 4) as the old (version 3). The upgrade code had to be rewritten for various reasons.

I'm creating a quick test application that will compare a version 3 Sql Server Express database and a version 4 Sql CE database. If the conversion logic is good, the databases should be exactly equivalent--same tables, same columns, same row values.

It would seem to me that there should be an easy way to do this using `DataTable.Merge` and `DataTable.GetChanges`, but I'm not having success. If rows exist in the version 3 database and not in the version 4 database, the `GetChanges` still returns null. If there are changes to the same rows (based on the primary key, which is a Guid), `GetChanges` still returns null.

```
string selectSql = String.Format("SELECT {0} FROM {1}", String.Join(", ", columns.ToArray()), tableName);

var expressAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(selectSql, expressConnection);
DataTable expressTable = new DataTable();
expressAdapter.Fill(expressTable);
expressTable.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { expressTable.Columns[tableName + "ID"] };

SqlCeConnection ceConnection = new SqlCeConnection(this.SqlServerCeConnectionString);
var ceAdapter = new SqlCeDataAdapter(selectSql, ceConnection);
DataTable ceTable = expressTable.Clone();
ceAdapter.Fill(ceTable);

expressTable.Merge(ceTable);
return expressTable.GetChanges(); // this is null even when the expressTable has rows that do not exist in ceTable.
```

Am I using `Merge` and `GetChanges` in a way too far removed from their intended use? If so, other options would be welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to do something similar sometime ago, but eventually it didn't work, because `AcceptChanges` was called on rows added by `Merge`, so they were all in unmodified state, so `GetChanges` returned null...

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure Merge doesn't do what you want it to.

If you check the expressTable.Rows.Count before and after the merge, you'll see what I mean.

Of course there are a lot of obvious ways to do this and they require a lot of work on your part. If you can you might want to consider a product like Red Gate Data compare

http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Data_Compare/index.htm

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're using this staff in an intended way.

In case you need to **compare** you'd better think in terms of having two data sources and keeping them in 'sync'. In case you want/need to do this automatically (via some code) you might want to take a look at [Microsoft Sync Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/default.aspx) which was specially developed for finding/resolving differences between data sources. In you case 'resolution' could be trivial (i.e. 'no action, report only'). In case this is a 'once-in-a-while' activity and you're OK with doing it manually, you can use some tool (RedGate Data Compare which was mentioned is quite OK for that, but I'm not 100% sure if it supports SQL Server CE).